# Grouping questions under a Template using Rails and Ancestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I am working on a Rails4.0 application in which I am using gem Ancestry for the hierarchy implementation. I have a Template model which has many questions. I have to be able to group and sub group these questions model. Each template can have many question groups and under these question groups I can have either many questions or question subgroups(but not both). By the way there are only two models involved 'Template' and 'Question'. For example:

```
Template
    QuestionGroup1
        Question_Subgroup1
             Question 1
             Question 2
    QuestionGroup2
        Question_Subgroup1
        Question_Subgroup2
    QuestionGroup3
        Question1
        Question2
        Question3
```

I hope the example is not confusing. Using Ancestry I am able to create a child under a parent but I am not able to do the grouping.  Please guide me in this regard.

I am posting the code below:

**Template Model**

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes.all? { |key, value| key == '_destroy' || value.blank? } }
end
```

**Question Model**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
  belongs_to :template
end
```

**On the Question Index.html.haml page this is the code below:**

```
%h4 Template Details
%hr
.row-fluid
  .span4
    %fieldset.template_outline
      %strong Template Outline
      %br
      = link_to 'Add Group', new_template_path(@template), id: "add_question_group"
      %hr
        = render 'questions_group'
    %br/
```

**Question_group Partial**

```
%ul.questions_group
    - @questions.roots.each do |question|
        %ul#questions_sub_group
        - question.subtree.each do |questions_sub_group|
            %li= link_to questions_sub_group.text_brief, edit_template_question_path(questions_sub_group.template, questions_sub_group)
        = link_to 'Add Question', new_template_requirement_path(@template, parent_id: requirement)
        = link_to 'Delete Question', [question.template, question], :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }
```

As you can see I am able to add and delete a single question. I want to be able to group them. Can it be done without using another model? The differnce between a questiongroup and a single question is that a group has only a "title", whereas a question has a "title" and "description".

Comment: There's no Group model?

Comment: i voted to close this question as it is not clear to me what you are asking. is this about javascript or ancestry or rails? what is the code you got, what is the error you run into?

Comment: jcm - Ya there is no group model. As I mentioned above, there are only two models 'Question' and ' Template'.

Comment: phoet: I am using Ancestry in a Rails application. Its not about javascript. I am asking for an idea of how to implement the concept of grouping in this hierarchy. It is not a specific error I am having.